# Lambda Linq Iqueryable group - add another grouping

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, iqueryable, linq-group

I have a method that I use for generating a summary report, based on the options a user selects in pick lists, to count the number of a type of test that is completed in a region, with subset locations, within a date range.

Here's what the data looks like:
Completed Test Counts by Location
From 1 FEB 2015 to 1 MAR 2015

```
Total  TestType  Location  Region  Division
455    24 Hour   Lab 1     City 1  Division A
28     24 Hour   Lab 2     City 1  Division A
95     24 Hour   Clinic Z  City 2  Division A
189    24 Hour   Clinic Y  City 2  Division A
```

Here's what it might look like for a different test type, at the same time period:

```
Total  TestType  Location  Region  Division
285    48 Hour   Lab 1     City 1  Division A
12     48 Hour   Lab 2     City 1  Division A
75     48 Hour   Clinic Z  City 2  Division A
106    48 Hour   Clinic Y  City 2  Division A
```

Now, the users would like to see the summary breakdown by `testType` in one report (in SQL, adding another attribute to a group by).  In my pick list of `testTypeId`, I am using 0 as my "All" item.  In a perfect world, I'd have another addition to the `IQueryable` if `testTypeId == 0`, so that I can keep the same private method, rather than writing a new query.

Here's what we'd like the data to look like in the "ALL" situation:

```
Total  TestType  Location  Region  Division
455    24 Hour   Lab 1     City 1  Division A
285    48 Hour   Lab 1     City 1  Division A
59     12 Lead   Lab 1     City 1  Division A
28     24 Hour   Lab 2     City 1  Division A
12     48 Hour   Lab 2     City 1  Division A
95     24 Hour   Clinic Z  City 2  Division A
75     48 Hour   Clinic Z  City 2  Division A
5      12 Lead   Clinic Z  City 2  Division A
189    24 Hour   Clinic Y  City 2  Division A
106    48 Hour   Clinic Y  City 2  Division A
8      12 Lead   Clinic Y  City 2  Division A
```

The example below shows what I have with what I'd like to add in it, but the syntax tells me I can't take an `IQueryable` containing an `IGrouping` and convert it to the target type of `IQueryable`.

Can anyone point me in a good direction here?

```
private CompletedCountReport GetCompletedCountsByRegion(int regionId, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int testTypeId)
{
    var ccRpt = new CompletedCountReport { CompletedCounts = new List<CompletedCount>(), StartDate = startDate, EndDate = endDate, SelectedRegionID = regionId};

    var query = HolterTestDao.FindAll(new GetCompletedByRegionIdAndDates(regionId, startDate.Value, endDate.Value));

    // a specific test type was selected
    if (testTypeId > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.HolterTestType == testTypeId);
    }
    // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD -> otherwise group by test type  <-  THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD.
    if (testTypeId == 0)
    {
        query = query.GroupBy(x => x.HolterTestType);
    }
    // order by locationID within the region.
    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Location.ID);

    var htList = query.ToList();

    // now Group by Location, to get counts. 
    var reportContents = htList.GroupBy(x => x.Location.ID);
    foreach (var r in reportContents)
    {
        var rList = r.ToList();

        var cc = new CompletedCount();
        var loc = LocationDao.FindById(r.Key);
        cc.Description = loc.Description;
        cc.RegionId = loc.Region.ID;
        cc.DivisionId = loc.Region.Division.ID;
        cc.TestTypeId = testTypeId;
        cc.Count = rList.Count;
        ccRpt.CompletedCounts.Add(cc);
    }

    return ccRpt;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to conditionally group the data?  Just *unconditionally* group the data.

Comment: So you are saying always group by both location and Test type?  Sometimes they want to see just numbers for just one test type, sometimes they want to see all test types

Comment: Got to tell us how you want the IGrouping resolved. If multiple items are bundled under one IGrouping then do you pick the first?

Comment: @JenniferS You can still conditionally filter the data, just don't conditionally group the data.  Always group, and then optionally filter (or the reverse).

Comment: I always want to group by location.  I only want to group by test type if "all" is selected, so I have individual counts by test type, otherwise I only want it for the selected test type

Comment: I dont get it. What's the point in grouping by testType when your "all" results are multiple testTypes grouped by location? You might as well just skip grouping by test type altogether.

Comment: I'm confused by your question because your 'all' data example is not grouped by testtype at all (it's just ordered/grouped by location) which I thought was what you were trying to but unable to do. If your goal is just to get a list that has all data grouped by location and each location grouped by testtype then I think you can simply use `OrderBy(x => x.Location.ID).ThenBy(x => x.HolterTestType)` on the `IQueryable` and vastly simply your code.

Comment: What I have obviously had was a failure to communicate correctly.  Thanks, all, for helping me think through this. My issue is not with the grouping of the data, but with my conditional logic that I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to OrderBy Location and HolterTestType, then GroupBy location for the basic contents, and then add another grouping in my loop through the results to get the counts by test type:

```
        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Location.ID).ThenBy(x => x.HolterTestType);
        var htList = query.ToList();

        // now Group by Location. 
        var reportContents = htList.GroupBy(x => x.Location.ID);

        foreach (var r in reportContents)
        {
            //Group by TestType, to get counts.
            var t = r.GroupBy(x => x.HolterTestType);
            var tList = t.ToList();

            foreach(var u in tList)
            {
                var cc = new CompletedCount();
                var loc = LocationDao.FindById(r.Key);
                cc.Description = loc.Description;
                cc.RegionId = loc.Region.ID;
                cc.DivisionId = loc.Region.Division.ID;
                cc.TestTypeId = u.Key;
                cc.Count = u.Count();
                ccRpt.CompletedCounts.Add(cc);
            }
        }
```